# React proxy creates double 'posts' in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, proxy

I'm trying to make proxy to the backend, it works on 'api/posts' but when I want 'api/posts/:id/blaa...' it sends request like 'posts/api/posts/:id...'.

Here is the log in the console from backend:

```
GET /api/posts 200 877.196 ms - 28709
GET /posts/api/posts/5b249d69b965e2776dbcf65e 404 0.566 ms - 179
GET /posts/api/comments 404 0.500 ms - 157
```

Here is the package.json from frontend:

```js
{
  "name": "reactfront",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.81.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

Here is how the fetch request look like:

```
const API_URL = "api";

export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_POSTS
  });
  fetch(API_URL + "/posts", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your URL in the `fetch(API_URL + "/posts", {` is relative (it is the "api/posts", perhaps it should be absolute ( "/api/posts").

Comment: What Do you have now? Urls in the console must be changed

Comment: `GET /api/posts 304 360.200 ms - -
GET /posts/api/posts/5b249d69b965e2776dbcf65e 404 7.608 ms - 179
GET /posts/api/comments 404 1.874 ms - 157`

Comment: I haven't used Github until now, hope it's okay: https://github.com/merko30/reactMediumLike

Comment: @merko, please double check your app, it works fine on my local machine. I have changed API_URL to the `const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api";`  because the server in our application works on the 5000 but this is the only thing. I don't see `/posts/api/posts/`